# WAMP Server Forbidden error

Tags: wampserver

I have been running a website I have been developing on WAMPserver.

When ever I try to access it through my IPv4 address on the computer that it is running on and any other device on the network I ge a error `403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server`.

Please help I kind of need it by a due date.

Comment: you have to choose `Put Online` from it's options menu in the notifications area.

Answer (score 2):

WAMPServer is designed as a development tool and not an environment for a LIVE site, so by default all the Apache security is based around allowing access from the PC running WAMPServer and nothing else.

If you want to open up your site to the world, you can use the menu item `Put Online`

```
left click wampmanager -> Put Online
```

If this does not work, usually becasue you have chnaged something in the httpd.conf file you can make the required changes manually.

Edit \wamp\bin\apache\apachex.y.z\conf\httpd.conf\httpd.conf

Find this section

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
```

And change it to

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
```

If you are using Apache 2.4.x the syntax has chnaged and you shoudl change it to

```
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require all granted
```

**BE VERY CAREFULL** not to change any other section to `Allow from all` or `Require all granted` as this can compromise you PC security very easily.